# How to get compare variables of a list individually?

Tags: python, arrays

So I have this code below that I'm trying to make, to where it will sort any list I give it so the lowest variable will be at the beginning, in position [0]. The problem I think is when the while loop comes in it compares uList[y] to the sum of uList[z:p] but, I was hoping it would compare it to each of the numbers individually so that if uList[y] is greater than ANY variable in uList[z:p] it would step into the loop how ever it does not. How would I go about making it compare the variables individually rather to the sum of them all, if that is whats happening.

Code:

```
import random
import sys
import os
import time
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()

y = 0
z = 1
x = 0
nNum = 1
uList = []
sList = []


listL = int(raw_input("How many elements would you like to be in your list?"))


clear()
while x < listL:
    uList.append(int(raw_input("Num %s:" %(nNum))))
    x = x + 1
    nNum = nNum + 1

p = len(uList) - 1

clear()
print("Your list was %s!" %(uList))

while z <= p:
    while uList[y] > uList[z]:
        j = uList[y]
        del uList[y]
        uList.append(j)

print(uList)
```

P.S. Any other tips or advice on anything about my code would be greatly appreciated as I am very obviously knew to python and coding in general lol, thank you so much!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you maybe want to sort the list?

Comment: I'm in trouble understanding your question. But you want to check if uList[y] is greater than the max of uList[z:p]?

if so the condition should be `uList[y] > max(uList[z:p])`

Edit : Pointed out in previous comment : you are trying to sort : if you want to sort, use built in function. If you wan't to do it with your own script, I let my comment.

Comment: Yes I want to sort but I want to write my own code to sort just for experience, and I want it to go into the while loop if uList[y] is greater than ANY  variable from uList[z:p], I think your code will work i would just have to change max to min. @T.Nel

Answer (score 0):

The comments under your answer suggest that you have already solved your problem but because you asked for some Python advice: the 'pythonic' way to iterate is by using a for loop with a `range` instead of a while loop.

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
```

Becomes:

```
for i in range(10):
    pass
```

If you want to get the indices of the sequence you are iterating over you can use enumerate.

```
my_list = [*range(10)] # this is basically a for loop creating a list

for index, element in enumerate(my_list):
    print(index, element)
```

This gives you:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 8
9 9
```

One last thing though. I am not sure if you are using Python 2 or 3 because you are using `raw_input` (Python 2) and `print()` (Python 2 or 3). If you are learning Python or programming in general I would recommend you go with Python 3 because it is easier to learn in some aspects and offers various improvements in efficiency and effectiveness.